# jQuery character and word count

Tags: jquery, text

This is a really simple question. Is it possible for jQuery to get an element, and count the number of words AND characters in that element (not a textarea or input) and echo it out on a HTML document? The only code that I could think of that may work is:

```
document.write("$('.content').text().length;")
```

I'm really bad at jQuery, but I'm trying to learn it. If anyone could provide a script, that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var txt = $('.content')[0].text()
  , charCount = txt.length
  , wordCount = txt.replace( /[^\w ]/g, "" ).split( /\s+/ ).length
  ;
$( '#somwhereInYourDocument' ).text( "The text had " + charCount + " characters and " + wordCount +" words" );
```

Running replace before split to get rid of punctuation, and running split with a regular expression to deal with new lines, tabs and multiple spaces in between words.

**EDIT** added the text( ... ) bit to write to a node, as the OP specified in a comment to another answer.

**EDIT** you still need to wrap it in a function to make it work after page load

```
$( function(){
    var txt = $('.content')[0].text()
      , charCount = txt.length
      , wordCount = txt.replace( /[^\w ]/g, "" ).split( /\s+/ ).length
      ;
    $( '#somwhereInYourDocument' ).text( "The text had " + charCount + " characters and " + wordCount +" words" );
});
```

Otherwise it runs before anything has been rendered on the page

Comment: This doesn't work.. Would you be able to provide a JSfiddle? I'm really bad at jQuery. :(

Comment: It probably depends on what you use to select the initial text. You didn't give us any HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/wt7JN/1/

Comment: Oh! Stupid me. The element getting "counted" would be #post, and the element that I need the text to show up in would be #postinformation. I'm using the exact code you sent me and it's not working.. D: http://jamestestblog3.tumblr.com take a look.

Comment: You still have to do the standard JQuery wrapping in a function etc to make work after the page has loaded... edited the question

Answer (score 3):

```
<span id="elementId">
We have here 8 words and 35 chars
</span>​

var text = $('#elementId').text();
var charsLength = text.length;           //35
var wordsCount = text.split(' ').length; //8
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKvNm/4/)

Comment: Didn't work. I need the script to get the number of words and characters and write it in the document also. BUT from my small knowledge of jQuery, it look like the only thing this is missing is the code that actually writes it out... Is there any chance you could provide that too? c:

Comment: `$('#IDofElementToWriteTo`).text(wordsCount + ' words (' + charsLength + ' characters).');`

Comment: @JamesCharless. Did that in a sec. Updated the fiddle, added a little animation just for the fun...

Comment: It works fine on the JSFiddle but it doesn't work at all on my page.. Could you take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong? The word + char count should show up in the div #postinformation. - http://jamestestblog3.tumblr.com/

Comment: @JamesCharless. You probably have problems with DOM ready... copy the new code in the fiddle. and read [this](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @gdoron I'm using the exact same code just edited the elements and it's still not working.. I have no clue what's wrong D:

Comment: @JamesCharless. It's `00:54` it my time zone. I'm going to sleep now... I can try to help you more tomorrow. Good night sir.