# Count Words and Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking to add a word and character count to a textarea using jQuery although all I've found are plugins to limit characters and words.

I would like to update in real-time, so that every time a user adds a character, or a word, the counter updates.

Is there a simple way to check for words and characters?

Comment: Use .length to check for character count. Word count usually doesn't matter, unless it is something like essay, since you can make a verrryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyloooooooooooooooooooooooongwooooooooooooooord.

Comment: $("textarea").html().split(" ").length

Comment: I hate sounding rude, but I googled "[jquery count words](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery+count+words&oq=jquery+count+words&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.973.5328.0.5436.18.8.0.9.9.0.200.715.7j0j1.8.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.L1JWGBTTwDs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=f42fee5d8e10998d&bpcl=40096503&biw=1235&bih=683)" and the [first result is exactly what you're looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422192/jquery-count-words-in-real-time). And for length, it's just .length. So you really didn't search very hard at all.

Comment: I've searched and haven't found anything that works

Comment: @evilone, this question is not ambiguous. Why it is closed ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```js
function wordCount(val) {
  var wom = val.match(/\S+/g);
  return {
    charactersNoSpaces: val.replace(/\s+/g, '').length,
    characters: val.length,
    words: wom ? wom.length : 0,
    lines: val.split(/\r*\n/).length
  };
}


var textarea = document.getElementById('text');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var wc = wordCount(this.value);
  result.innerHTML = (`
   <br>Characters (no spaces):  ${wc.charactersNoSpaces}
   <br>Characters (and spaces): ${wc.characters}
   <br>Words: ${wc.words}
   <br>Lines: ${wc.lines}
  `);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it update real time?

Comment: Sure added a demo in my answer

Comment: It works! Thank you! Also, I tried to [add this](http://jsfiddle.net/deepumohanp/jZeKu/) although I got a syntax error, do you know what it'll do that?

Answer (score 9):

```
char_count = $("#myTextArea").val().length;
word_count = $("#myTextArea").val().split(" ").length;
```

Comment: This is a very bare-bones approach, but it doesn't take in to account trailing white space or multiple space characters in succession, which in a manual approach would not be considered a new word.

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = $('.content')[0].text()
  , charCount = txt.length
  , wordCount = txt.replace( /[^\w ]/g, "" ).split( /\s+/ ).length
  ;
$( '#somwhereInYourDocument' ).text( "The text had " + charCount + " characters and " + wordCount +" words" );
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864644/jquery-character-and-word-count)

Answer (score -1):

W/O jQuery:

```
this.innerHTML gives you the textarea content.  
this.innerHTML.length gives you the number of characters.
```

With jQuery:

```
$(this).html()
```

etc.

I'm sure you can come up with a simple word counting algorithm.

Comment: Textarea has content in HTML not in value.

Comment: I've tested it. Both possible .val(), .html()....

Comment: although I changed the no-jquery part to innerHTML, but just checked and you CAN use .value, it's value from this context, both are fine

Comment: W3C do not define value attribute in textarea element in html 4. Value attribute can be browser dependent.

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var count = jQuery("#textboxid").text().length;
});
```

Comment: I don't want to limit the words and characters, I just want to count them

Comment: length is attribute, String has not method length()