# Using JQuery to count all the words in a blog post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a function using `jQuery` that will scan through my entire blog post and calculate the estimated read time for the user.

Currently I've done the following to get the amount of words in each paragraph:

```
$('p').each(function(){
     var v = wordCount($(this).html()); 
     totalWords = totalWords + v.words;
 );

function wordCount(val){
          var wom = val.match(/\S+/g);
          return{
          charactersNoSpaces: val.replace(/\s+/g, '').length,
          characters: val.length,
          words: wom ? wom.length: 0,
          lines: val.split(/\r*\n/).length
  }
}
```

Thank you to the poster on this question for the `wordCount` function: [Word and Character Count using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010446/word-and-character-count-using-jquery)

The above works fine and I get the output I expect for my paragraphs. However my Blog post will consist of a combination of `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `ul`,`ol`, `span`,`p`, `li`.

So I modified my code like this:

```
$('p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul li, ol li, span').each(function(){
     var v = wordCount($(this).html()); 
     totalWords = totalWords + v.words;
});
```

But now the results are skewed. For example If I have a `span` tag within a paragraph or a list item or whatever it counts it twice.

So for example this Markup should return 8, instead I get 9.

```
<ul>
      <li>This is a test</li>
      <li>This is <span>another</span> text</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone advise me on a possible fix, there is obviously an error in my logic and I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Your blog post description start with any div having any unique id.

Comment: The entire contents of my blog post are contained in a wrapper with an `id` so once my logic is fixed I was going to target all elements within this wrapper for the word count

Comment: Use `text()` instead of `html()`. USE `var v = wordCount($(this).text());`

Comment: @OmasuPlus yes but the issue is that nested elements are being counted twice

Comment: `$('#post').text()` where `#post` is the id of the container. You really don't have to count every element separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `text()` to get the *textContent* of the element.

```
var v = wordCount($(this).text());
```

If `html()` is used, the elements, for example, `<h1>` and `</h1>` will be counted as words.

Comment: Hi @Tushar thank you for your answer, I've updated as you mentioned but I am still getting the same result - it seems as though my nested elements are being counted twice

Comment: @Javacadabra You need to pass as selector the main article container, not each nested elements and btw, you should trim it (in some cases): `var v = wordCount($(this).text().trim());`

Comment: @Javacadabra As the selector `p` is used, if there are paragraph elements nested, the code will run twice. Use the specific element selector as said in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying

`var v = wordCount($(this).html());`

to

```
var v = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().html();
v = wordCount(v);
```

Source:
[Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)