# Contenteditable word count including default text

Tags: javascript, css

I have this:

```js
document.getElementById('editor').addEventListener('input', function () {
    var countThis = this.textContent,
     count = countThis.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length;
    document.querySelector('.words').textContent = count;
     });
```

```css
#editor {background: silver; outline: 0;}
.words {background:aqua;}
```

```html
<main id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    Default text...
</main>
<div class="words"></div>
```

The script start counting once I start typing. But I want it to also count when the page is loaded, showing the default text word count first. Any ideas? *Javascript only, please.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply make a reusable function:

```js
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
var words =  document.querySelector('.words');

function wordsCount () {
  var content = editor.textContent.trim(),
    count = content.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length;
 words.textContent = count;
}


editor.addEventListener('input', wordsCount);
wordsCount();
```

```css
#editor {background: silver; outline: 0;}
.words {background:aqua;}
```

```html
<main id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    Default text...
</main>
<div class="words"></div>
```

### What if there's no text?

If you remove all text you might also want to show there's `0` words!

```js
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
var words =  document.querySelector('.words');

function wordsCount () {
  var arr = editor.textContent.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');
  words.textContent = !arr[0] ? 0 : arr.length;
}

editor.addEventListener('input', wordsCount);
wordsCount();
```

```css
#editor {background: silver; outline: 0;}
.words {background:aqua;}
```

```html
<main id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    Default text...
</main>
<div class="words"></div>
```

To find out more stuff, see: [**Word and character counter**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14010497/383904)

Comment: That’s just perfect. Thank you!